# Trouble Uploading Sketch - Issues with SPISettings

Tags: arduino-mega, spi, uploading, error

Full disclosure - I'm very new to Arduino. I am probably missing something simple. However, I've scoured the internet and can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to use an Arduino Duo Wifi rev2 to install a bootloader onto my Ender 3 (3D printer) - see: https://howchoo.com/g/mge1mdfkzjv/ender-3-bootloader-firmware-update-marlin

When I try to upload the ArduinoISP sketch, I get the following error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.12 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2, ATMEGA328"

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/brandonbarks/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:megaavr:uno2018:mode=on -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_cache_822969 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -verbose /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/brandonbarks/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:megaavr:uno2018:mode=on -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10812 -build-path /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_cache_822969 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avrdude/6.3.0-arduino17 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arduinoOTA/1.3.0 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5.path=/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5 -verbose /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino
Using board 'uno2018' from platform in folder: /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6
Detecting libraries used...
/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -DMILLIS_USE_TIMERB3 -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/sketch/ArduinoISP.ino.cpp -o /dev/null
Generating function prototypes...
/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -DMILLIS_USE_TIMERB3 -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/sketch/ArduinoISP.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp
Compiling sketch...
/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino5/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega4809 -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10812 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO_WIFI_REV2 -DARDUINO_ARCH_MEGAAVR -DUNO_WIFI_REV2_328MODE -DMILLIS_USE_TIMERB3 -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/deprecated -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino -I/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/variants/uno2018 /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/sketch/ArduinoISP.ino.cpp -o /var/folders/sc/1v4cm6053k7bmhv2bd02k44w0000gn/T/arduino_build_226513/sketch/ArduinoISP.ino.cpp.o


ArduinoISP:191:27: error: reference to 'SPISettings' is ambiguous
     void beginTransaction(SPISettings settings) {
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino:167:7: note: candidates are: class SPISettings
 class SPISettings {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/ArduinoAPI.h:31:0,
                 from /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23,
                 from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino:39:
/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/HardwareSPI.h:37:7: note:                 class arduino::SPISettings
 class SPISettings {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
ArduinoISP:191:27: error: 'SPISettings' has not been declared
     void beginTransaction(SPISettings settings) {
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino: In member function 'void BitBangedSPI::beginTransaction(int)':
ArduinoISP:192:39: error: request for member 'clock' in 'settings', which is of non-class type 'int'
       pulseWidth = (500000 + settings.clock - 1) / settings.clock;
                                       ^~~~~
ArduinoISP:192:61: error: request for member 'clock' in 'settings', which is of non-class type 'int'
       pulseWidth = (500000 + settings.clock - 1) / settings.clock;
                                                             ^~~~~
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino: In function 'void start_pmode()':
ArduinoISP:410:24: error: reference to 'SPISettings' is ambiguous
   SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(SPI_CLOCK, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino:167:7: note: candidates are: class SPISettings
 class SPISettings {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/ArduinoAPI.h:31:0,
                 from /Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:23,
                 from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/examples/11.ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP/ArduinoISP.ino:39:
/Users/brandonbarks/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/megaavr/1.8.6/cores/arduino/api/HardwareSPI.h:37:7: note:                 class arduino::SPISettings
 class SPISettings {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
exit status 1
reference to 'SPISettings' is ambiguous
```

If anyone has any advice, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What type of Arduino are you actually using? There is no Arduino Duo. Possibly you meant Arduino Uno or Arduino Due, though you tagged the question with Arduino Mega. Which one is it?

Comment: update the megaavr core